# How to change citation style for articles in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I am editing the bibliography of my thesis with biblatex but in literature and in France we have very specific rules to cite documents. I use `verbose` citestyle and bibstyle to have my citations in a footnote, but the citation style for the articles doesn't meet my needs.
Here's my example:

```
\documentclass[french,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-trad2,citepages=omit,bibstyle=verbose,isbn=false,doi=false,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{\subsubsection*{#1}}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph} % pour mettre ibid, op. cit. et loc.cit. en italique
%pour mettre "éditeur, ville, date":
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{% 
    \printlist{location}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
    in = {dans}%
}
%pour mettre la date de l'édition utilisée juste après l'année originale
\renewbibmacro{date}{%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{##1}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \addspace%
    \printfield{edition}%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{}
%\bibliography{bibliotheseA}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{TrillingCalvino1962,
    title = {Calvino in musica},
    author = {Trilling, Ossia},
    date = {1962-01},
    journaltitle = {Sipario},
    volume = {XVII},
    keywords = {2caa},
    langid = {italian},
    number = {189}
}
@book{ValeryEgo1992,
    title = {Ego scriptor},
    author = {Valéry, Paul},
    date = {1992},
    publisher = {{Gallimard}},
    location = {{Paris}},
    keywords = {2lit},
    langid = {french}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
    Some text.\autocite{ValeryEgo1992}
    Other text.\autocite{TrillingCalvino1962}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For some reason the book citation doesn't work with me but anyway it is not a problem on my document. The problem is the result of the article citation:

[image: result article citation]

I would like the citation to be like this:
Trilling, Ossia, "Calvino in musica", *Sipario*, n°189, vol. XVII, 1962.

Or, more generally:

`<SURNAME>, <Name>, "<title>", *<journaltitle>*, n°<number>, vol.<volume>, <date>.`

I was able to manage to change the order and style for books, but not for articles. Any idea?

Comment: Usually in `biblatex` `@article`s `number` is a subdivision of `volume`. I can't quite tell if that is the case here or if you want the opposite (`volume` is a subdivision of` `number`). Of course it would be possible to just invert the fields, but when you want to be able to reuse your `.bib` file with other styles, it may be a good idea to stick to the original semantic and only change the presentation. Can you explain how that is meant here?

Comment: I am not sure I want to invert the fields in the `.bib` file. I was wondering if there is a way to use a `\renewbibmacro` command related to `@article` just like I did for `@book`s.

Comment: Sure, you can `\renewbibmacro` something together for that, but before I'd want to go into that I'd first like to understand the semantics of what is going on here. Which field is the subdivision of the other here? Or are they both independent? Assume you were to publish part of your work in an American journal with APA style, what should the citation look like there?

Comment: In the journals I usually use for my research, I would say that `volume` is a subdivision of `number` because some numbers have several volumes. Sometimes the `volume` field is empty, the more important is `number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `biblatex` `@article`s `number` is always a subdivision of `volume`. If in your case *volume* is a subdivision of *number* I'd probably be inclined to swap the two fields in the input to still maintain consistency with other styles. I will first show a solution doing that and will then explain what needs to be done to exchange `volume` and `number` if you insist that is necessary.

Taking `biblatex-ext`'s `ext-verbose-trad2` as a basis many required changes can just be done by modifying punctuation macros.

```
\documentclass[french,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[french=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-verbose-trad2,
  sorting=ynt,
  articlein=false,
  isbn=false, doi=false,
  citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{edition}{}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\locpubdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\pubdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  in      = {dans},
  jourvol = {vol\adddot},
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{TrillingCalvino1962,
  title        = {Calvino in musica},
  author       = {Trilling, Ossia},
  date         = {1962-01},
  journaltitle = {Sipario},
  number       = {XVII},
  keywords     = {2caa},
  langid       = {italian},
  volume       = {189},
}
@book{ValeryEgo1992,
  title     = {Ego scriptor},
  author    = {Valéry, Paul},
  date      = {1992},
  publisher = {Gallimard},
  location  = {Paris},
  edition   = {4},
  keywords  = {2lit},
  langid    = {french},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Some text.\autocite{ValeryEgo1992}
  Other text.\autocite{TrillingCalvino1962}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Ossia Trilling, « Calvino in musica », Sipario, n o 189, vol. XVII, jan. 1962.]

---

If you insist on exchanging `volume` and `journal` you also need to modify the bibmacro `volume+number+eid`.

```
\documentclass[french,a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[french=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-verbose-trad2,
  sorting=ynt,
  articlein=false,
  isbn=false, doi=false,
  citepages=omit]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\numvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit*{\numvoldelim}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{edition}{}

\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\locpubdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\pubdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  in      = {dans},
  jourvol = {vol\adddot},
}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{TrillingCalvino1962,
  title        = {Calvino in musica},
  author       = {Trilling, Ossia},
  date         = {1962-01},
  journaltitle = {Sipario},
  volume       = {XVII},
  keywords     = {2caa},
  langid       = {italian},
  number       = {189},
}
@book{ValeryEgo1992,
  title     = {Ego scriptor},
  author    = {Valéry, Paul},
  date      = {1992},
  publisher = {Gallimard},
  location  = {Paris},
  edition   = {4},
  keywords  = {2lit},
  langid    = {french},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Some text.\autocite{ValeryEgo1992}
  Other text.\autocite{TrillingCalvino1962}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly well, thank you.
I have some other questions about biblatex but I have to do some research first. Do I post them here as answers or do I create a new topic?

Comment: @Martin Please ask a new question if you have a new question. (The answer space is reserved for answers only. And a question should ideally not be edited significantly after it was answered). If the answer helped you you may want to consider accepting it by clicking on the little green checkmark on the top left (https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ok so I will ask a new question. I accepted the answer, thanks again, you were very helpful.